# Calculating subtotals in pandas pivot_table with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following raw data, in a dataframe:

```
   BROKER    VENUE  QUANTITY
0  BrokerA  Venue_1       300
1  BrokerA  Venue_2       400
2  BrokerA  Venue_2      1400
3  BrokerA  Venue_3       800
4  BrokerB  Venue_2       500
5  BrokerB  Venue_3      1100
6  BrokerC  Venue_1      1000
7  BrokerC  Venue_1      1200
8  BrokerC  Venue_2     17000
```

I want to do some summarization of the data to see how much each broker sent to each venue, so I created a pivot_table:

```
pt = df.pivot_table(index=['BROKER', 'VENUE'], values=['QUANTITY'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Result, as expected:

```
                 QUANTITY
BROKER  VENUE            
BrokerA Venue_1     300.0
        Venue_2    1800.0
        Venue_3     800.0
BrokerB Venue_2     500.0
        Venue_3    1100.0
BrokerC Venue_1    2200.0
        Venue_2   17000.0
```

I also want how much was sent by each broker overall. and show it in this same table. I can get that information by typing `df.groupby('BROKER').sum()`, but how can I add this to my pivot table as a column named, say, BROKER_TOTAL?

Note: This question is similar but seems to be on an older version, and my best guess at adapting it to my situation didn't work: [Pandas Pivot tables row subtotals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570099/pandas-pivot-tables-row-subtotals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) for `df1`, [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) it to `pt` and last [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('BROKER').sum()
df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1.index + '_total', len(df1.index) * ['']])
print (df1)
                QUANTITY
BrokerA_total       2900
BrokerB_total       1600
BrokerC_total      19200

print (pd.concat([pt, df1]).sort_index())
                       QUANTITY
BROKER        VENUE            
BrokerA       Venue_1       300
              Venue_2      1800
              Venue_3       800
BrokerA_total              2900
BrokerB       Venue_2       500
              Venue_3      1100
BrokerB_total              1600
BrokerC       Venue_1      2200
              Venue_2     17000
BrokerC_total             19200
```

Comment: I can get the max of ```QUANTITY``` using ```df.groupby('BROKER').max()```. But how to print the ```VENUE```  ?

Comment: @Akira Can you check `df.loc[df.groupby('BROKER')['QUANTITY'].idxmax()]` ?

Comment: What if I have a groupby with two columns? @jezrael