# Pandas: How to include all columns and all indexes for multiple pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am trying to create pivot tables for different locations from the following dataframe (`df`):

| Location | Category | Status | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Furniture | New | $100 |
| 1 | Furniture | Old | $50 |
| 2 | Office Supplies | New | $200 |
| 1 | Furniture | New | $100 |
| 1 | Office Supplies | New | $300 |
| 1 | Office Supplies | Old | $150 |

First, I have filtered the dataframe to separate for location 1 & 2 with code:

```
df1 = df[df['Location'] == 1]

df2 = df[df['Location'] == 2]
```

Next I have used the standard pandas pivot table function:

```
pd.pivot_table(df1, values='Price', index='Status', columns='Category', aggfunc=np.sum)

pd.pivot_table(df2, values='Price', index='Status', columns='Category', aggfunc=np.sum)
```

So I have the following two pivot tables as output:

**Location 1:**

| Status | Furniture | Office Supplies |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New | $200 | $300 |
| Old | $50 | $150 |

**Location 2:**

| Status | Office Supplies |
| --- | --- |
| New | $200 |

However, I want the pivot table for location 2 to include all possible categories and statuses and have 0 if they are not present. To summarize, I want the following pivot table for location 2:

**Location 2:**

| Status | Furniture | Office Supplies |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New | $0 | $200 |
| Old | $0 | $0 |

I have gone through all the options of the pivot_table() function, but haven't found anything to solve this so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the pivot table before splitting by `Location`.

For [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

- set index with `index=['Location', 'Status']`
- pass parameter `dropna=False` to allow all categories to show up for all `Location` and all `Status` even when empty. (Default is to hide empty entries).
- pass parameter `fill_value=0` to fill up `NaN` values as `0`

Then locate `Location` from the pivot table by [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), as follows:

```
df_out = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                        values='Price', 
                        index=['Location', 'Status'], 
                        columns='Category', 
                        aggfunc=np.sum, 
                        dropna=False, 
                        fill_value=0)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

Category         Furniture  Office Supplies
Location Status                            
1        New           200              300
         Old            50              150
2        New             0              200
         Old             0                0
```

Then, to get the pivot table only for `Location` 2, you can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), as follows:

```
df2 = df_out.loc[2]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df2)

Category  Furniture  Office Supplies
Status                              
New               0              200
Old               0                0
```

### Edit (for adding Total and Sub-total)

If you also want to include the **Total** (for all `Location`) and **Sub-total** (for each `Location`), you can also do it, as follows:

For [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

- pass parameter `margins=True` and `margins_name='Total'` to set up the margins for **Total** (grand total for all `Location`)
- chain the command `fillna(0, downcast='infer')` after [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).  This is to handle the *glitch / bug* of [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) that the margin total will still show `NaN` for empty entry (e.g. `Location=2` `Status='Old'` in this case) even when `fill_value=0` parameter is specified.

```
df_out = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                        values='Price', 
                        index=['Location', 'Status'], 
                        columns='Category', 
                        aggfunc=np.sum, 
                        dropna=False, 
                        fill_value=0,
                        margins=True,
                        margins_name='Total'
                        ).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

**Result**

```
print(df_out)

Category         Furniture  Office Supplies  Total
Location Status                                   
1        New           200              300    500
         Old            50              150    200
2        New             0              200    200
         Old             0                0      0
Total                  250              650    900
```

Then, to add the **Sub-total** (for each `Location`), we further use:

```
(pd.concat([df_out, 
            df_out.query('Location != "Total"')
                  .groupby(level=0).sum()
                  .assign(Status='Sub-total')
                  .set_index('Status', append=True)])
   .sort_index())
```

**Result:**

```
Category            Furniture  Office Supplies  Total
Location Status                                      
1        New              200              300    500
         Old               50              150    200
         Sub-total        250              450    700
2        New                0              200    200
         Old                0                0      0
         Sub-total          0              200    200
Total                     250              650    900
```

Comment: This answer serves the primary purpose. Thanks a lot. However, the reason I filtered before applying the pivot_table() function was I wanted to include the total in margins. Applying the pivot table without filtering makes everything simpler, but now I don't have the totals for each location. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @EkaraiGlass  Oh, I see. You also set margins in the pivot table.  For the subtotals, suggest you have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62605470/pandas-pivot-table-subtotals-with-multi-index) and may be [this post too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979196/sub-total-in-pandas-pivot-table)

Comment: The first post solves the problem perfectly

Comment: @EkaraiGlass   Yes, it's a very good solution.   I'm also just going to edit my solution to include this part.

Comment: @EkaraiGlass  I've also customized the codes for adding sub-totals for you based on the reference post I passed you. You can take a look.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for such an elegant solution, @SeaBean